# Leaflet interactive styling does not reset style correctly on mexican state geojson layer

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I adapted the leaflet tutorial for an interactive choropleth map to create hover highlights and zoom functionality to my Mexican states map.

Oddly, when I test out the highlight it leaves certain states highlighted.

Demo at garciamaps.com/mexico

Here is the the js.

```
//GETS BASEMAP TILES
var greyscale =    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/gregorydgarcia.kg672h90/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');

//INITIALIZES BASEMAP LAYER
var baseMaps = {
 "Basemap": greyscale,
};

//INITIALIZES MAP
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [19.00, -99.1333],
    zoom: 5,
    layers: [greyscale]
});


//FUNCTIONALITY FOR STATES
var stateStyle = {
    "color": "#3D5229",
    "weight": 1,
    "opacity": .90
};

function getColor(d) {
    return  '#800026';
}

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties) {
         layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
     }
 }

var geojson;
geojson = L.geoJson(estados, {
    style: stateStyle
        });

function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;

    layer.setStyle({
         weight: 5,
         color: '#666',
         dashArray: '',
         fillOpacity: 0.8
    });

    if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
        layer.bringToFront();
    }
    info.update(layer.feature.properties);
}

function resetHighlight(e) {
    geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
    info.update();

}

function zoomToFeature(e) {
   map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
}

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
        click: zoomToFeature
    });
}

geojson = L.geoJson(estados, {
    style: stateStyle,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);

//ASSIGNS LAYERS TO MAP
L.control.layers(baseMaps).addTo(map)

var info = L.control();

info.onAdd = function (map) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class  "info"
    this.update();
    return this._div;
};

// method that we will use to update the control based on feature properties passed
info.update = function (props) {
    this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>Mexican State</h4>' +  (props ?
        '<b>' + props.name + '</b>'
        : 'Hover over a state');
};

info.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the highlight opacity is sometimes maintained even though you call [resetStyle](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-resetstyle). Explicity set fillOpacity in stateStyle, and it should work as expected.

```
//ALL FOR STATES
var stateStyle = {
    "color": "#3D5229",
    "weight": 1,
    "opacity": .90,
    "fillOpacity": .90
};
```

Note, you are also declaring the variable named geojson twice, but I don't think that is the problem

Comment: Fixed it perfectly! Thank you! I'll leave the map up as is for others with similar issues for about a month.